# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:Could Not initialize class org.apache.calcite.avatica.ConnectionPropertiesImpl

Tags: java, classloader, noclassdeffounderror

Application A depends on arrange-client.jar, and arrange-client.jar depends on calcite.jar. When I call the method methodX in arrange-client.jar in the A application, NoClassDefFoundError is displayed when new ConnectionPropertiesImpl()

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAByP.jpg)

Comment: Did you read the _javadoc_ for class [java.lang.NoClassDefFound](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html)? Here is a quote: _The searched-for class definition existed when the currently executing class was compiled, but the definition can no longer be found._ This means that the CLASSPATH for compiling your project is not the same as the one you use for running your project.

Answer (score 1):

kindly check for the version of java that is installed in your system and the version that is in the IDE you are working with, make sure both were same else you will get the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError